# Bit selector in buffer

Tags: node.js, parsing, binary, buffer

I have to parse a 8 byte buffer like

```
"000000000000402B"h (= "0000...100000000101011"b).
```

But **this data is like a selector**, so if bit 0 is set to 1, then there is a valueA data who will be first on queue, if bit 1, then valueb is queued...
For the example, the queue will be :

```
<valueA><valueB><valueD><valueF><valueO>
```

After this, i will have a JSON file who will describe each type of value, like :

```
[
    {
        "name" : "valueA",
        "type" : "int32",
        "size" : 4
    }
    {
        "name" : "valueB",
        "type" : "uint8",
        "size" : 1
    }
    ...
    . .
    .   .
]
```

I suggest the **bitwise operation**, but maybe is it not the best way to do it.

With NodeJS, do you know **one method to perform this good** ?

Comment: `Bitwise` or you `toString` the value and use `String` parsing

Comment: The data is stored as a buffer

Comment: You can use [toString](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) on the `Buffer`

Comment: yes, but are you sure is it the best way to parse the selector ?

Comment: Like when you use boolean for boolean operation, number to store number and string to store string, bitwise are the most accurate tool when manipulating binary data. You should use it. But if you are not comfortable with them you can use the string parsing. [Here](https://jsperf.com/rounding-numbers-down/3) is a benchmark about data manipulation (string and bitwise) you i'll see that bitwise is significantly faster.